# Doble funcion "event.target" multiple

Tags: javascript, html, funciones, eventos, click

estoy creando un tooltip sencillo con este código pero me gustaría que cuando clickeo el "item 2" cierre el "ul" del "item 1" o a la inversa. Es decir, que cada clickeo haga doble función, la de abrir el que le corresponde y cerrar el que pueda estar abierto.

```
function handler( event ) {
  var target = $( event.target );
  if ( target.is( "li" ) ) {
    target.children().toggle();
  }
}
$( "ul" ).click( handler ).find( "ul" ).hide();
```

Comment: Hla joselm, puedes compartir tu codigo html para ponernos en contexto y poder ayudarte? De todos modos puedes ocupar la funcion .off de jquery, aqui tienes un ejemplo de la documentacion, espero que te sirva https://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: Aquí tienes el desarrollo. https://jsfiddle.net/joselm65/nfchk6bx/3/

Comment: Puedes colocar ese código aquí mismo, edita la pregunta y usa un _Fragmento de código_, funciona igual que _jsfiddle_, pero sin tener que abrir otra pestaña.

Comment: Triby ya lo había intentado, pero si inserto el código me dice que es demasiado en comparación con el resto de mensaje. O sea que no me deja a no ser que meta más información.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No funciona como lo esperas porque al hacer clic simplemente muestras u ocultas el elemento que quieres, sin tomar en cuenta el resto.

Basta analizar si el elemento a mostrar está oculto para saber que debe mostrarse y, por tanto, no debe haber otro visible.

```
$('li.nombre').click(e => {
    // Saber en qué elemento se hizo clic
    let target = $(e.target);
    if(target.children('.CV-especialista').css('display') == 'none') {
        // Está oculto y se va a mostrar, ocultar los demás
        $('.CV-especialista').css('display', 'none');
    }
    // Mostrar u ocultar
    target.children('.CV-especialista').toggle();
});
```

Por cierto, es más fácil si trabajas directamente con los elementos deseados, como podrás notar, cambié los 'ul' por 'li.nombre' para trabajar solo con los elementos de lista con clase *nombre* y los 'li' por '.CV-especialista' para identificar las tarjetas que se van a mostrar u ocultar.

Comment: Fantástico!! Muchas gracias Triby, funciona perfectamente. Buena lección.

Comment: No olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada, por favor.